# How to retrieve a GL2 instance?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, openglcontext

I am currently writting a game with the JOGL bindings to use OpenGL but I am so struggling on this.

I need to initialize my vaos and vbos (for each component) using the GL2 variable that I collected in the init method in the class that implements GLEventListener. Like so,

```
public abstract class Scene implements GLEventListener {
    private GL2 gl;

    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        ...
```

But this variable is null when I want to use it because it appears it's before the call of the method init (which is strange to me). I also checked GLContext.getCurrent() to maybe retrieve a GL instance but the context is also null.

So I wonder where is the context created and what triggers the init function above  ?

Maybe I could simply make a boolean that tells when a component as been initialized in my render function, so maybe the GL init method would have been called.

Comment: GLEventListener.init(GLAutoDrawable) is the right place to do that, what's wrong? Have you looked at our examples in the wiki?

Comment: The fact that I don't know the number of components (components can be added during the game loop or deleted), i can't allocate for all of them in the GLEventListener.init(GLAutoDrawable). I'll take a look to the wiki anyway, thx.

Comment: Found on the jogl wiki, links for jogl examples target porn video urls... Can you share the example you were speaking of, that would help me !

Comment: There is no such content in our wiki, you probably confuse it with something not hosted on our website. I advise you to have a look at this: https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Jogl_Tutorial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GL context usually gets created when the window is made visible for the first time, but it's platform specific - could be when the window is created, could be immediately before your program starts drawing. The init() method will get invoked before the first display() but again there's no guarantee about exactly when this happens.

My advice for JOGL is not to store the GL context permanently. Instead every init(), display(), reshape() starts with

```
GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
```

On some platforms trying to use the GL context outside of one of these methods won't work/crashes the program, so making the context local also stops you writing code that could do so.

It's also possible that the context could change, if the user say moves the window onto a display controlled by a different GPU.

Comment: It's an excellent advise. I explained many times on our official forum the risks of manipulating the GL instance when the OpenGL isn't current or when it's current on another thread or when it has been invalidated in the meantime.

Comment: So is it a better option to make each component implementing GLEventListener ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by component. A GL context is usually created for a window, responsible for managing all the on- and off-screen framebuffers, textures, and whatnot. (Note that creating a context is NOT part of the OpenGL API itself, it is different on different operating systems.) There's usually a way to share geometry/textures etc between contexts, but you can do a lot of good 3D with just one window and one context.

Comment: This was a bad answer of me sorry, I think this post lost me. I was speaking of component as entity in the game, or game objects if you prefer. If I had one last question, that would be : where do i allocate vao (not in GLEventListener.init but it needs a gl instance) ?

Comment: I have finaly won over the issue. I had to move ``GL11.glViewport(0, 0, videoMode.width(), videoMode.height());`` after this ``glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);`` Thx a lot you two, for sharing your advices and knowledge, you were so useful